# Flash IDE Compiler runs at double speed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, lag, frame-rate

I've searched, but haven't found an answer for this yet, so.

About 5% of the time I launch my game with ctrl+enter and test the movie in Flash CS6, the game turns from 60 FPS to what seems like 120 FPS randomly, though with an FPS counter it still reads 60. It flicks on and off until I close the program. But this only happens when I launch it, about 5% of the time, usually it works just fine. What could be causing this?
I don't think it's anything do the with the code because it randomly does this right on launch.

--

Also on a different note, when I launch my game in the external SWF file it is able to hand about 100 bitmapped enemies on screen, and when I launch it in the test IDE or launch the SWF using internet explorer it can handle 500. What would be effecting the speed in the external SWF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, it happens to me some times but i don't know why.
For the second question, maybe the version of the player may cause this, the debug and release player don't have same performances.